# loginpage first in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working with an MVC3 (razor) application. In the default sample program, how can a user get the login page first, then to allow registered users to enter into homepage?

I tried to create one but landed in bunch of errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188915/where-is-the-default-page-in-mvc3) question

now, just change code like
    controller = "Account", action = "LogOn"

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the default action in the route config.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "LoginController", action = "loginView", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

in Global.asax file, RegisterRoutes method

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

you just need to change controller and action for default route.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in the Application_Start method in your Global.asax:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute())
```

and decorate your login action with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute